# Can I import variables into R from a global file?

Tags: r, makefile

I am integrating an R script to produce some graphics into a larger project that is pulled together with a Makefile. In this larger project, I have a file called `globals.mk` that contains global variables used by many other scripts in the project. For example, the number of simulations I want to run is a global that I want to use in this R script. Can I "import" this as a variable, or is it necessary to manually define every variable within the R script?

Edit: here is a sample of the globals that I would need to read in.

```
num = 100
path = ./here/is/a/path
file = $(path)/file.csv
```

And I would like the R script to set the variables `num` as 100 (or "100"), `path` as "./here/is/a/path" and `file` as "./here/is/a/path/file.csv".

Comment: You definitely can, but how you'd do it depends on the format of the `globals.mk` file. The easiest way is to [source an R file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11051187/reading-and-using-a-custom-configuration-file), but there are options for other formats like [YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272846/how-to-get-parameters-from-config-file-in-r-script?noredirect=1&lq=1) and others. Please post an example of your file, or specify what (if any) constraints are placed on that file

Comment: If global.mk contains lines like `num = 100` (which is valid R source code) then in your R program use `source("global.mk")` to read it in and run it.  If it is not valid R source then use `readLines` to read it in and do whatever processing you need to extract and set the values from the character vector that `readLines` returns.  Note that questions should include a complete minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks, I've added more details and clarified the requirements.

Comment: You can pass command line parameters when you call an R script. Right now it's unclear exactly how you are calling the script. Please try to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that we can actually run and test with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is ok to replace the parentheses with brace brackets then `readRenviron` will read in such files and perform the substitutions returning the contents as environmental variables.

```
# write out test file globals2.mk which uses brace brackets
Lines <- "num = 100
path = ./here/is/a/path
file = ${path}/file.csv"
cat(Lines, file = "globals2.mk")

readRenviron("globals2.mk")
Sys.getenv("num")
## [1] "100"
Sys.getenv("path")
## [1] "./here/is/a/path"
Sys.getenv("file")
## [1] "./here/is/a/path/file.csv"
```

If it is important to use parentheses rather than brace brackets, read in globals.mk, replace the parentheses with brace brackets and then write the file out again.

```
# write out test file - this one uses parentheses as in question
Lines <- "num = 100
path = ./here/is/a/path
file = $(path)/file.csv"
cat(Lines, file = "globals.mk")

# read globals.mk, perform () to {} substitutions, write out and then re-read
tmp <- tempfile()
L <- readLines("globals.mk")
cat(paste(chartr("()", "{}", L), collapse = "\n"), file = tmp)
readRenviron(tmp)
```

Comment: This is perfect! Sys.getenv() allows me to call the variable, which is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If the `.mk` file has anything other than direct variable expansion (such as more complex `make`-rules/tricks/functions), it might be better to trust `make` to do the expansion for you, and then read it in. There's a post [here](https://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/dumping-every-makefile-variable) that I found that dumps all variable contents (after processing).

### TL;DR

```r
expand_mkvars <- function(path, aslist = FALSE) {
  stopifnot(file.exists(mk <- Sys.which("make")))
  tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".mk")
  # needed on my windows system
  tf <- normalizePath(tf, winslash = "/", mustWork = FALSE) # tempfile should suffice
  on.exit(suppressWarnings(file.remove(tf)), add = TRUE)
  writeLines(c(".PHONY: printvars",
               "printvars:",
               "\t@$(foreach V,$(sort $(.VARIABLES)), \\",
               "\t   $(if $(filter-out environment% default automatic, \\",
               "\t   $(origin $V)),$(warning $V=$($V))))"), con = tf)
  out <- system2(mk, c("-f", shQuote(path), "-f", shQuote(tf), "-n", "printvars"),
                 stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE)
  out <- out[grepl(paste0("^", tf), out)]
  out <- gsub(paste0("^", tf, ":[0-9]+:\\s*"), "", out)
  known_noneed <- c(".DEFAULT_GOAL", "CURDIR", "GNUMAKEFLAGS", "MAKEFILE_LIST", "MAKEFLAGS")
  out <- out[!grepl(paste0("^(", paste(known_noneed, collapse = "|"), ")="), out)]
  if (aslist) {
    spl <- strsplit(out, "=")
    nms <- sapply(spl, `[[`, 1)
    rest <- lapply(spl, function(a) paste(a[-1], collapse = "="))
    setNames(rest, nms)
  } else out
}
```

In action:

```r
expand_mkvars("~/StackOverflow/karthikt.mk")
# [1] "file=./here/is/a/path/file.csv" "num=100"                       
# [3] "path=./here/is/a/path"         

expand_mkvars("~/StackOverflow/karthikt.mk", aslist = TRUE)
# $file
# [1] "./here/is/a/path/file.csv"
# $num
# [1] "100"
# $path
# [1] "./here/is/a/path"
```

I have not tested on other systems, so you might need to adjust `known_noneed` to add extra variables that popup. Depending on your needs, you might be able to filter more-intelligently (e.g., none of your variables lead with a capital letter), but for this example I kept it to the known-not-wanted variables that `make` is giving us.

---

The [blog post](https://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/dumping-every-makefile-variable) suggests using a phony target of

```
.PHONY: printvars
printvars:
    @$(foreach V,$(sort $(.VARIABLES)), \
       $(if $(filter-out environment% default automatic, \
       $(origin $V)),$(warning $V=$($V))))
```

(some are tabs, not all spaces, very important for `make`)

Unfortunately, it produces more output than you technically need:

```
$ /c/Rtools/bin/make.exe -f ~/StackOverflow/karthikt.mk printvars
C:/Users/r2/StackOverflow/karthikt.mk:10: .DEFAULT_GOAL=all
C:/Users/r2/StackOverflow/karthikt.mk:10: CURDIR=/Users/r2/Projects/Ford/shiny/shinyobjects/inst
C:/Users/r2/StackOverflow/karthikt.mk:10: GNUMAKEFLAGS=
C:/Users/r2/StackOverflow/karthikt.mk:10: MAKEFILE_LIST= C:/Users/r2/StackOverflow/karthikt.mk
C:/Users/r2/StackOverflow/karthikt.mk:10: MAKEFLAGS=
C:/Users/r2/StackOverflow/karthikt.mk:10: SHELL=sh
C:/Users/r2/StackOverflow/karthikt.mk:10: file=./here/is/a/path/file.csv
C:/Users/r2/StackOverflow/karthikt.mk:10: num=100
C:/Users/r2/StackOverflow/karthikt.mk:10: path=./here/is/a/path
make: Nothing to be done for 'printvars'.
```

so we need a little filtering, ergo the majority of code in the function.

---

**Edit**: it the `readRenviron`-to-envvar is the best way for you, it would not be difficult to redirect the output of this `make` call to another file, parse out the relevant lines, and then do `readRenviron` on that new file. It seems more indirect due to the use of two temp files, but they're cleaned up so that should be nothing to worry about.

Comment: Also hinted at here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7119460 (and other answers there)