# Writing a wrapper function for connecting to PostgreSQL database in a R package

Tags: r, postgresql

I'm writing a R package for the first time. Its called `aactr` and is hosted on my GitHub: https://github.com/jasonbaik94/aactr

Right now, the package only has one function, `aact_connect`:

```
aact_connect <- function(user, password) {

  drv <- DBI::dbDriver('PostgreSQL')
  con <- DBI::dbConnect(drv,
                   dbname="aact",
                   host="aact-db.ctti-clinicaltrials.org",
                   port=5432,
                   user=user,
                   password=password)

}
```

My concern is that users of my package wouldn't like to input their username and password in their R script for privacy reasons.

What would be a nice workaround to ensure user privacy?

One thought I had: When the user types `aact_connect()`, a window pops up where the user can input `username` and `password` and press Enter, after which the connection would be made. Also, for those without a username or password, I'd put a parameter, `init_connection = TRUE`, after which this sign up page would load: https://aact.ctti-clinicaltrials.org/users/sign_up

Any others suggestions are greatly welcome!

Comment: This is a solved problem.  I mentored the development of the initial (and still widely used) RPostgreSQL package during Google Summer of Code some ten or twelve years ago ... and already then did we use proper environment variables (as opposed to scripts) as described in part 2. of @Parfait's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to securely handle database credentials in scripts. See few examples below:

1. Use configuration files such as yaml saves securely on user's machines for R to read into needed variables. See [@Spacedman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5276466/1422451).

   **config.yaml**

   ```
   db:
    host : localhost
    port : 5432
    name : mypgdb
    user : pg_useR
    pwd  : ***
   ```

   **R**

   ```
   library(yaml)
   config = yaml.load_file("/path/to/config.yml")

   dbConnect(drv, host = config$db$host, port = config$db$port,
             dbname = config$db$name, 
             user = config$db$user, password = config$db$pwd)
   ```
2. Use environmental variables that are linked to user or system profiles:

   ```
   db_creds <- Sys.getenv(c("DB_HOST", "DB_PORT", "DB_NAME", "DB_USER", "DB_PWD"))

   con <- DBI::dbConnect(drv,
                         dbname = db_creds[['DB_NAME']],
                         host = db_creds[['DB_HOST']],
                         port = db_creds[['DB_PORT,']],
                         user = db_creds[['DB_USER']],
                         password = db_creds[['DB_PWD']])
   ```
3. Use DSNs that maintains connection parameters but requires an ODBC connection which can be run with the generalized `odbc` package (part of same DBI family as `RPostgreSQL`). Postgres maintains up-to-date [odbc drivers](https://odbc.postgresql.org/) for most operating systems. See [R-bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/connecting-r-to-postgresql-on-linux/).

   **odbc.ini**

   ```
   [myPG_DSN]
   Driver = PostgreSQL Unicode
   Database = mypg_db
   Servername = localhost
   UserName = pg_useR
   Password = ***
   ```

   **R**

   ```
   db <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "myPG_DSN")
   ```

Comment: I'm running with the first option. However, how do I get the user of my `aactr` package to input his username and password into the yaml file?

Comment: In docs, describe how yaml file should be set up and pass in the yaml path as function argument.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the "pass in the yaml path as function" part, but not sure about how I should set up the yaml file in a package?

Comment: The yaml file should be the user-created config file with their trusted credentials (outside package).

Comment: Ah that makes so much sense.

Comment: Do you have an examples of R packages that are similar to `aactr`, which has wrapper functions to allow users to easily access SQL database?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not. Most R packages either provide one solution: data store, data handling, special modeling, etc. rarely more. Do be aware your package will add dependencies if it relies on other packages and external data stores which too can change versions (i.e. Postgres 9, 10, 11) outside your control.